# how can I determine the path of a site using php/smarty?

Tags: php, url, smarty, if-statement

Ok, say I have a page with the url: `URL.com/checkout/completed`, how can I setup an if statement to perform:

```
<if "This page has url of checkout/completed">

No Content

<else>

Content

</if>
```

Is there a way? A simple way, my php/smarty-fu lacks.. A lot.

EDIT:

```
{if $smarty.server.REDIRECT_URL eq 'http://www.euroworker.no/checkout/completed'}
&nbsp;
{else}  
<div id="scrollwrap">   
    <div class="scrollFieldContent"> 

Scrolled content
        </div>

<div class="probetalings">Velg betalingsmåte</div>

{include file="/choosePaymentMethod.tpl"}
</div> 

{/if}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` and `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'];`

```
if($_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'] == 'checkout/completed') {
   echo 'Some content';
}
```

in smarty:

```
{if $smarty.server.REDIRECT_URL eq 'checkout/completed'}
Some content
{/if}
```

If you don't have REDIRECT_URL set, and use REQUEST_URI, you might want to use `strstr` instead of typical comparison in case you just want to match that URI while ignoring any additional parameters which might be sent, or go with `SCRIPT_NAME` as @Pekka suggested:

```
if(strstr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'checkout/completed')) {
   echo 'Some content';
}
```

EDIT: Try:

```
{if $smarty.server.REQUEST_URI eq '/checkout/completed'}
```

Comment: A perfectly fine answer but why `REDIRECT_URL`? It's not set when I call a PHP script in my WAMP setup. Doesn't that only apply when there is a redirect of some sort?

Comment: @Pekka - my setup has it for some reason. I threw in `REQUEST_URI` additionally in case OP doesn't have `REDIRECT_URL`. Possibly to do with mod_rewrite and my ZF setup.

Comment: @karim I see. Note though that `REQUEST_URI` will contain any GET parameters passed: `/checkout/completed?a=b&c=d&e=f` you will need to take that into consideration when doing the comparison.

Comment: Sorry guys, but none of this is working :( Will update my question. with the code.

Comment: @Kyle Sevenoaks - $smarty.server.REQUEST_URI eq '/checkout/completed'

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer `SCRIPT_NAME` that will return the full request path but not the query string like `REQUEST_URI` does.

```
if ($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"] == "/checkout/completed")
 ......
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by script name. Do I have to attach another script to this?

Comment: @Kyle sorry, no, this is about the question which `$_SERVER` variable to use. Those are pre-set variables defined by the web server, available in every script through the `$_SERVER` array. `SCRIPT_NAME` is one of them. There are several very similar variables but they behave differently under different circumstances (and sometimes, server setups). Try the `if(...)` condition as quoted above.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I should go home and learn PHP more. 

+1